# How to change column type from CHAR to DATE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I saved a date field as CHAR before, now I want to use Sequelize migration to update the date field to DATE from CHAR. The format of the date column is `2021-03-08T20:09:49Z` in UTC.

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn("my_table", "my_date_col", {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  },
```

But I got this error: `ERROR: column "my_date_col" cannot be cast automatically to type.`
I would like to ask how to cast a CHAR to DATE in Sequelize for Postgres DB? Thank you.

Comment: In plain SQL, this would be: `alter table my_table alter my_date_col type timestamp using my_date_col::timestamp;` - you need to find a way to provide the `using ...` part to your obfuscation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. You need to cast the CHAR to TIMESTAMP first and then set it as DATE type.

The drawback of this method is that it will convert the existing data from UTC to my local time zone, but I am cool with it.

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn("my_table", "my_date_col", {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP USING CAST("my_date_col" as TIMESTAMP)',
      });
      await queryInterface.changeColumn("my_table", "my_date_col", {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn("my_table", "my_date_col", {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  },
};
```